# I am writing eMMC driver in linux and access the IOCTL from JNI application. It is failed with error code 13(Permission denied)

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

A) I am writing an eMMC driver in Linux to access the IOCTL from "Linux" application. It is working.
B) I am writing an eMMC driver in Linux to access the IOCTL from "JNI" application. It is failed with error code 13(Permission denied).

1. Where to set the permission in android application?
2. Is it possible to access IOCTL from JNI Application?
3. Is there any settings in Android.mk file for permission (in JNI)?

Answer (score 0):

The application must be running with suitable permissions for the thing you are trying to `ioctl` on. In the case of Android+JNI, this is probably almost never the case if you require root permissions (unless the device is "rooted" and the application is started as root), since it is likely that the native application you are calling will run as the same UID as the Java application. Can you verify whether you require root permissions for what it is you are trying to `ioctl`?